# Eclipse Zest draw connection by dragging

Tags: eclipse, zest

I have created a viewer with a Zest graph inside. I would like to create a connection between two nodes by dragging (e.g. using the right mouse button) the first node and dropping it to the second one.

How can I make this?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Dragging is usually done with the left button; the right button is to open the context menu.

Comment: One button should be for moving nodes over the viewer and the other for dragging.